# Sum of positive random variables

Tags: probability, expected-value

Suppose $(X_n)_{n}$ is a sequence of positive random variables. Suppose
$$
\sum_{n \geq 0} E[X_n] < \infty.
$$
Can we conclude that $\sum X_n < \infty$ almost surely? If we have independence should be true, I was wondering if it is true also without independence.

Comment: What does this have to do with independence? And yes, you can conclude that; it's essentially trivial

Comment: It is essentially direct from the definition. If $F$ is the distribution of $X$ then $E(X) = \int_\mathbf{R} x dF(x) + \infty P(X = \infty),$ where we impose the condition $\infty \times 0 = 0.$

Comment: Note that $\sum X_n < \infty$ (almost surely) $\nRightarrow \sum E[X_n] < \infty$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X:=\sum_{n=0}^\infty X_n$.  Since the $X_n$ are a.s. positive, $X$ is as well, and it follows from Tonelli's theorem that
$$
\infty\cdot \mathbb P(X=\infty)\leqslant\mathbb E[X]=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \mathbb E[X_n] <\infty,
$$
and hence $\mathbb P(X=\infty)=0$ (under the usual convention that $0\cdot\infty =0$ for the extended real line).